# Error when selecting nothing in listbox

Tags: c#

Hi I have a code that reads a text file and copies the content into a list box.
Everything is working fine, but when I click inside the listbox in a place where there is no item, a new error message appears and it points out that I have somthing wrong with this line:

```
switch (listBox3.SelectedItem.ToString()) {
    case "Accessories":
        label4.Text = "None Required"; //Approval
        label13.Text = " "; //Approval
        label5.Text = "TTS";  //sent by
        label6.Text = "IT Co.";   //sender
        label7.Text = "2";  //urgent
        label8.Text = "3";  //normal
        label9.Text = "PC Name";   // required filed 1
        label10.Text = "PC Brand && Model";  // required filed 2
        label11.Text = "B.C";  // required filed 3
        label12.Text = "Location";  // required filed 4
        label14.Text = "User Name";  // required filed 5
    break;
```

This just a piece of the code and the line which the compiler points out is this:

```
switch (listBox3.SelectedItem.ToString())
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this fix:

```
if(listBox3.SelectedItem != null) {
    switch (listBox3.SelectedItem.ToString()) {
        case "Accessories":
            label4.Text = "None Required"; //Approval
            label13.Text = " "; //Approval
            label5.Text = "TTS";  //sent by
            label6.Text = "IT Co.";   //sender
            label7.Text = "2";  //urgent
            label8.Text = "3";  //normal
            label9.Text = "PC Name";   // required filed 1
            label10.Text = "PC Brand && Model";  // required filed 2
            label11.Text = "B.C";  // required filed 3
            label12.Text = "Location";  // required filed 4
            label14.Text = "User Name";  // required filed 5
        break;
    }
}

else {
    //nothing selected
}
```

Comment: this will give you error complete the bracket of the switch case

Comment: thanx that fix it and you was the first one to answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to check for the selectcted item is it null or not

```
if (listBox3.SelectedItem!=null)
{

  // write code for it 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

To attempt to sum up what everyone has said:

```
if(listBox3.SelectedItem != null) {
    switch (listBox3.SelectedItem.ToString()) {
        case "Accessories":
            label4.Text = "None Required"; //Approval
            label13.Text = " "; //Approval
            label5.Text = "TTS";  //sent by
            label6.Text = "IT Co.";   //sender
            label7.Text = "2";  //urgent
            label8.Text = "3";  //normal
            label9.Text = "PC Name";   // required filed 1
            label10.Text = "PC Brand && Model";  // required filed 2
            label11.Text = "B.C";  // required filed 3
            label12.Text = "Location";  // required filed 4
            label14.Text = "User Name";  // required filed 5
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: The else section of the conditional statement is not required as was shown in the selected answer.

Answer (score 2):

Attempting to call `ToString()` (or any method for that matter) from a `null` value will yield NRE's.  `SelectedItem` would end up being `null` if there is nothing selected.  You would either have to check for `null` beforehand or use `Convert.ToString()` to do this as it doesn't throw when given a `null` value, it just returns the string `"null"`.

```
switch (Convert.ToString(listBox3.SelectedItem))
{
    // etc...
}
```